# Etymologie von „Eltern“

Tags: etymology

Gemeinhin wird angenommen, dass *Eltern* irgendwie mit *alt* verwandt ist. Entsprechend wurde im Rahmen von Rechtschreibreformen die alternative Schreibweise *Ältern* vorgeschlagen. Stimmt diese etymologische Beziehung wirklich und wie kann man sich diesbezüglich sicher sein?

Ich würde eher eine Verbindung zum indoeuropäischen Verwandtschaftsmorphem {**tʰer*} vermuten, das u. a. in *Mutter, Vater, Schwester, Vetter, Bruder, Tante(?), Geschwister, Gevatter, Kinder(?); mother, father, sister, brother; pater, mater, frater* steckt.

Comment: War das Deine [Quelle](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Eltern)? Es gäbe ausserdem noch die Generalisierung Verwand-_ter_ .

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nee, aber ich hätte im DWDS nachschauen sollen. Der „substantivierte Plural des Komparativs“ ist ja schon eine ziemlich genaue Herkunft, die schwerlich anzuzweifeln ist.

Answer (score 5):

> Gemeinhin wird angenommen, dass Eltern irgendwie mit alt verwandt ist. Entsprechend wurde im Rahmen von Rechtschreibreformen die alternative Schreibweise Ältern vorgeschlagen. Stimmt diese etymologische Beziehung wirklich und wie kann man sich diesbezüglich sicher sein?

Ich gebe mal zwei Quellen dazu an:

- [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Eltern)

  > > Eltern Plur. ‘Vater und Mutter’, ahd. altiron, eldiron (8. Jh.), mhd. altern, eldern, eltern, asächs. eldiron, mnl. ouderen, nl. ouders, aengl. eldran, yldran **ist der substantivierte Plural des Komparativs** (westgerm. *aldizōn-) von dem unter ↗alt (s. d.) behandelten Adjektiv. Ältern findet sich oft im 16., vereinzelt noch im 18./19. Jh.; die Schreibung mit e setzt sich endgültig durch, seitdem der Zusammenhang mit alt nicht mehr erkannt wird. Fachsprachlich, besonders in der Psychologie, wird seit Anfang des 20. Jhs. der rückgebildete Singular Elter m. n. für ‘Elternteil’ verwendet.
- [Indogermanische Ursprache (Wikipedia)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indogermanische_Ursprache#Suffixe)

  > > *méh₂tēr, *ph₂tḗr, *bʰréh₂tēr, *dʰugh₂tḗr → Mutter, Vater, Bruder, Tochter
  > >     – nicht aber Schwester, da aus *swésōr entstanden, oder Eltern (aus dem Komparativ die Älteren)[image]

Das sollte Deine Frage im Wesentlichen beantworten.

> Ich würde eher eine Verbindung zum indoeuropäischen Verwandtschaftsmorphem {*tʰer} vermuten, das u. a. in Mutter, Vater, Schwester, Vetter, Bruder, Tante(?), Geschwister, Gevatter, Kinder(?); mother, father, sister, brother; pater, mater, frater steckt.

Die ethymologische Herkunft von *Schwester oder Eltern* fällt demnach nicht unter die Herkunft der indogermanischen Wortbildungsstruktur mit dem Suffix *-h<sub>2</sub>ter*, sondern ist **der substantivierte Plural des Komparativs**.

Für die letztere Quelle ist sicherlich auch der einleitende Test zum Begriff *indoeuropäisch* relevant (ich habe hervorgehoben was *"... und wie kann man sich diesbezüglich sicher sein?"* betrifft):

> > Die indogermanische Ursprache (oder: indogermanische Grundsprache bzw. Urindogermanisch) ist die **nicht belegte, aber durch sprachwissenschaftliche Methoden erschlossene gemeinsame Vorläuferin** (Ursprache) der indogermanischen Sprachen. Für diese Sprachfamilie ist (vor allem international) auch die Bezeichnung „Indoeuropäisch“ üblich,[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7sI5.png)

Comment: +1 Ausführliche Antwort. Anzufügen wäre vielleicht noch, dass der Komparativ einen Primärumlaut hat. Dies bedeutet, dass schon im Althochdeutschen die Schreibung mit ⟨e⟩ anzutreffen ist, während die Schreibung mit ⟨ä⟩ erst viel später autritt.

Comment: "Die ethymologische [sic] Herkunft von Schwester oder Eltern fällt demnach nicht unter die Herkunft der indogermanischen Wortbildungsstruktur mit dem Suffix -h2ter, sondern ist der substantivierte Plural des Komparativs". Im Falle von "Schwester" stimmt das nicht.

Comment: @fdb _"Im Falle von "Schwester" stimmt das nicht."_ Hmm, ich habe eigentlich nur zitiert, was die im Bild gezeigte Tabelle der Quelle aussagt. Hast Du bielleicht eine bessere Quelle, die Deine Postulation untermauert?

Comment: "nicht aber Schwester, da aus *swésōr entstanden"

Comment: Man spricht dabei von Angleichung an das Paradigma, oder Analogie, solange es keinen Grund gibt, einzig die germanische Variante als ursprünglich anzusetzen. Es sieht doch wohl jeder, dass es kein zufälliger Lautwandel zum *t* hin war.